# How do i set the velocity of a sprite to the opposite direction of the mouse pointer at a certain speed?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

/*I am making a 2d game in Unity that works similarly to billiards, but with other aspects. When the player holds down button 0, a line drags away from the ball to show the direction and speed the ball will be hit off in. I don't know how to set that velocity or how to add a force like that.

I've tried setting the velocity directly, then adding fake frictions, but that didn't work too well. I also tried adding a force to the ball, and also making an empty game object that follows the pointer with a point effecter to repel the ball. But I cant seem to get anything to work. 
      --Also I apologize for the messy code, i'm still kinda new to this
*/

```
using System.Collections;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class LineDrawer : MonoBehaviour
{
public Transform tr; //this is the transform and rigid body 2d of the 
ball
public Rigidbody2D rb;
public LineRenderer line; // the line rendered is on the ball 
public float hitForce = 10;
// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    line = GetComponent<LineRenderer>();
    line.SetColors(Color.black, Color.white);

}

// Update is called once per frame
void FixedUpdate()
{
    line.SetPosition(0, tr.position - new Vector3(0, 0, 0));

    if (Input.GetMouseButton(0)&&PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Moving")==0)
    {
        line.SetWidth(.25f, .25f);
        line.SetPosition(1, Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition));
        float len = Vector2.Distance(line.GetPosition(0), line.GetPosition(1)); //this is for determining the power of the hit


    }
    else
    {
        line.SetWidth(0, 0); //make the line invisible
    }
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0) && (PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Moving")==0))
    {
        Vector2.Distance(Input.mousePosition, tr.position)*100;
         Debug.Log("Up");
        rb.velocity = //this is what i cant work out
         PlayerPrefs.SetInt("Moving", 1);

    }
}
```

}

//5 lines from the bottom is where i'm setting the velocity.

Comment: By the way, `Update` is called once a frame like your comment states, but `FixedUpdate` does not. It operates on the physics ticks, however quickly those are calculated. I would retrieve input through `Update`, but apply the physics-based changes in `FixedUpdate`

Comment: @Eliasar ok thx

Comment: "_I've tried setting the velocity directly, then adding fake frictions, but that didn't work too well._"  What didn't work, specifically?  Was the direction correct? What do you mean by fake frictions?

Comment: @Foggzie by fake friction I mean subtract a bit of the velocity through code, instead of using a physics material. The big problem I’m having is how to make the ball move in a certain direction when the mouse is released. I don’t know if I should use rb.addForce or use rb.velocity = or use a point effecter

Comment: @camocStudios_Hagger Well if your line renderer is looking correct, that means you've already got the right directional vector to use between the first and second points of the line.  `rb.AddForce` and `rb.velocity = ` should both work for what you want to do.

Comment: @Foggzie how do I add the force to the ball?

Comment: @camocStudios_Hagger Get the vector for the direction, normalize it, multiply it by whatever magnitude you'd like, then choose a [`ForceMode`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ForceMode.html) (Either `Impulse` or `VelocityChange` would be best).

Comment: @Foggzie I’ll try that, thanks

Comment: What version of Unity are you using? Because some of those line renderer functions are obsolete.

Comment: @SeanCarey I’m using the latest one, I think it’s v5?

Comment: @camocStudios_Hagger That is definitely not the latest one. It at least 2 years old.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

Just rewrite your script to the following:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class Ball : MonoBehaviour
{

    private LineRenderer line; 
    private Rigidbody2D rb;

    void Start()
    {
        line = GetComponent<LineRenderer>();
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        line.SetPosition(0, transform.position);

        if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
        {
            line.startWidth = .05f;
            line.endWidth = .05f;
            line.SetPosition(1, Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition));           
        }
        else
        {
            line.startWidth = 0;
            line.endWidth = 0;
        }

        if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0))
        {
            Vector2 direction = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition) - transform.position;
            direction.Normalize();
            rb.AddForce(direction * 3f, ForceMode2D.Impulse);       
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow! Thank you so much for the help!